# why firebase not sending me spam message on my main E-mail account? here is my android studio kotlin code:

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

```
buttonSendEmail.setOnClickListener {

    val email = editTextEmail.text.toString()

    if(email.isNotEmpty()){
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().sendPasswordResetEmail(email)
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if(task.isSuccessful){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Check E-mail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

everything is fine, I think, but actualy not working :/ If someone has any idea, please help me.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is. When you run this code, what happens? And what did you expect to happen?

Comment: I think that code is not a key, if i click reset password in firebase website, email still not received.

Comment: 1. How long did you wait? 2. Did you check your spam folder? 3. What is the email host you're testing with? Did you check all spam filters between the google servers and that host (i.e. reach out to the system admins for those systems)?

Comment: everything is default in templates tab, i haven't changed enything. if this is a problem, how can i fix it? i mean templates tab in my project at firebase website.

Comment: I asked 3 concrete questions that will help us figure out what may be going on. Please answer those.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.